# What happening when you copy application to application folder in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

How to know where are files coped in Mac OS X filesystem?
And which files?

UPD: I ask this questions because I found some files from the applications in other directories, not just in /Applications (i.e. ~/Library). So are these files created after I run the application ? (not in copying ?) Lots of people told that copying application is like installation in Mac OS X, so I think application can put some files, preferences in other directories when it's "installing".

Answer (score 0):

The application folder on Mac OS X is `/Applications`.

Applications in OS X (files that end in .app) are actually directories. Everything in the .app directory gets copied to to /Applications. When you put an app in your app folder, you're just copying a directory that ends in .app to the /Applications directory.

You can do `ls -l /Applications/Preview.app` on the command line to confirm this.

Comment: But I find some files from the application in other directories, i.e. ~/Library. So are these files created after I run the application ? (not in copying ?) I ask this question because copying application is like installation in Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, the app will create files in ~/Library when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Applications on the Macintosh are permitted to write to some specific directories for their own purposes. Most of these directories are in the Library, either the system library

```
 /Library/...
```

or the user’s library

```
 /Users/...username.../Library/....
```

which is conventionally written ~/Library/...

Inside these folders, you might find Preferences (where applications store their preference settings), Application Support (where applications store things like templates and customizable resources), Logs (where applications might write a crash log if things go wrong), Caches (for storing information like web pages), and Services (for things that are launched from the Services menu).

In general, applications shouldn't install LARGE things in these folders without asking.  So there’s not much reason to worry about the files that applications install here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that apps can use the following to copy those files even before the app has ran:

```
Applications can contain a helper application as a full application bundle,
stored inside the main application bundle in the Contents/Library/LoginItems directory.
Set either the LSUIElement or LSBackgroundOnly key in the Info.plist file of the helper
application’s bundle.
```

See more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html

You can see this functionality by copying the latest version of Docker for Mac OS X to the Applications folder but not running it.